# How to call restful API (Authenticated endpoints) in SSIS for ETL

Tags: rest, ssis, etl, restful-authentication

I'm relatively new to SSIS and restful API(AND every type of API), it's a bit hard to figure out the topic for me.

So how to call restful API in SSIS to ETL?
I don't get this;
If the problem is to call the API using data from a table like this:

[image: click to see the table]

(and because the actual information cannot be revealed I had to censor it.) I don't know how to call it. How to arrange them? I want an example.

If anyone knows how to call or a way to learn about creating API URLs, please tell me.

p.s. I'm sorry if the question and detail about this problem that I typed seems short or strange I am not good in English.

I have already found out through research is:

You can call an API from your own code within a script task, but for that you need .NET or C# experience. [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/182096/calling-a-restful-api-in-ssis-and-returning-output)

I try to call restful API (authenticated endpoints) in SSIS for ETL.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to call APIs in SSIS (without installing an Extension) is with a language like C# in a Script Task. [This seems to be a good example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/726424/write-c-code-to-get-the-data-from-rest-api-using-s) you could use.

My team chose to purchase the [ZappySys SSIS Powerpack](https://zappysys.com/products/ssis-powerpack/), which is an Extension that gives you a load of powerful SSIS tasks, including a few REST API tasks. There *is* a learning curve to use these, although I'd argue it's easier than going the script route. Since you are new to SSIS and APIs, if you choose to buy SSIS Powerpack I would recommend using their [community forums](https://community.zappysys.com/) to supplement the documentation.